# Laravel Docker Swoole Error when following Laravel Install

Tags: laravel, docker

I've been following the get started on macOS for Laravel and I'm coming across the following error when running

```
./vendor/bin/sail up

[ 5/12] RUN pecl install swoole:
#9 0.616 No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/swoole"
#9 0.616 install failed
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pecl install swoole]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new update on Laravel sail :

https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/99

You can now run `composer update` and `sail up`